# Can't connect the site theme switcher from Preline UI

Tags: javascript, next.js, tailwind-css

Tried plugging in a 'Button Togle' it worked, but I don't need it. I need "Select", but I can't connect it....

**The component where the theme change button is located**
The code for the button is taken ready-made from the official Preline UI documentation

```
import {usePathname} from "next/navigation";
import Link from "next/link";
import Navigation from "./Navigation";


export default function TheHeader() {

  return (
    <>
    <header className="select-none z-50 bg-white dark:bg-zinc-900 fixed w-full h-16 border-b border-solid border-zinc-300/80 dark:border-zinc-800/80">
      <div className="px-20 h-full flex">
        <div className="self-center flex flex-1">
          <img src="/logo_header.png" alt="Logo" className="h-12" />
          <div id="name-version">
            <div className="text-lg lg:block ml-2 font-extrabold text-black dark:text-zinc-50">CodeCraft | Vanilla</div>
            <div className="lg:block ml-2 font-normal text-sm text-black dark:text-zinc-300 -mt-1">2 сезон</div>
          </div>
        </div>
          <Navigation />
          <div className="flex flex-1 justify-end">

        
          {/* ChangeTheme */}
          <div class="hs-dropdown" data-hs-dropdown-placement="bottom-right" data-hs-dropdown-offset="30">
  <a class="hs-dropdown-toggle hs-dark-mode group flex items-center text-gray-600 hover:text-blue-600 font-medium dark:text-gray-400 dark:hover:text-gray-500" href="javascript:;">
    <svg class="hs-dark-mode-active:hidden block w-4 h-4" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
      <path d="M6 .278a.768.768 0 0 1 .08.858 7.208 7.208 0 0 0-.878 3.46c0 4.021 3.278 7.277 7.318 7.277.527 0 1.04-.055 1.533-.16a.787.787 0 0 1 .81.316.733.733 0 0 1-.031.893A8.349 8.349 0 0 1 8.344 16C3.734 16 0 12.286 0 7.71 0 4.266 2.114 1.312 5.124.06A.752.752 0 0 1 6 .278zM4.858 1.311A7.269 7.269 0 0 0 1.025 7.71c0 4.02 3.279 7.276 7.319 7.276a7.316 7.316 0 0 0 5.205-2.162c-.337.042-.68.063-1.029.063-4.61 0-8.343-3.714-8.343-8.29 0-1.167.242-2.278.681-3.286z"/>
    </svg>
    <svg class="hs-dark-mode-active:block hidden w-4 h-4" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
      <path d="M8 11a3 3 0 1 1 0-6 3 3 0 0 1 0 6zm0 1a4 4 0 1 0 0-8 4 4 0 0 0 0 8zM8 0a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v2a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-2A.5.5 0 0 1 8 0zm0 13a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v2a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-2A.5.5 0 0 1 8 13zm8-5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-2a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h2a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5zM3 8a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-2a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h2A.5.5 0 0 1 3 8zm10.657-5.657a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .707l-1.414 1.415a.5.5 0 1 1-.707-.708l1.414-1.414a.5.5 0 0 1 .707 0zm-9.193 9.193a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .707L3.05 13.657a.5.5 0 0 1-.707-.707l1.414-1.414a.5.5 0 0 1 .707 0zm9.193 2.121a.5.5 0 0 1-.707 0l-1.414-1.414a.5.5 0 0 1 .707-.707l1.414 1.414a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .707zM4.464 4.465a.5.5 0 0 1-.707 0L2.343 3.05a.5.5 0 1 1 .707-.707l1.414 1.414a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708z"/>
    </svg>
  </a>

  <div id="selectThemeDropdown" class="hs-dropdown-menu hs-dropdown-open:opacity-100 mt-2 hidden z-10 transition-[margin,opacity] opacity-0 duration-300 mb-2 origin-bottom-left bg-white shadow-md rounded-lg p-2 space-y-1 dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border dark:border-gray-700 dark:divide-gray-700">
    <a class="hs-auto-mode-active:bg-gray-100 flex items-center gap-x-3.5 py-2 px-3 rounded-md text-sm text-gray-800 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:text-gray-400 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:hover:text-gray-300" href="javascript:;" data-hs-theme-click-value="auto">
      Auto (system default)
    </a>
    <a class="hs-default-mode-active:bg-gray-100 flex items-center gap-x-3.5 py-2 px-3 rounded-md text-sm text-gray-800 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:text-gray-400 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:hover:text-gray-300" href="javascript:;" data-hs-theme-click-value="default">
      Default (light mode)
    </a>
    <a class="hs-dark-mode-active:bg-gray-700 flex items-center gap-x-3.5 py-2 px-3 rounded-md text-sm text-gray-800 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:text-gray-400 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:hover:text-gray-300" href="javascript:;" data-hs-theme-click-value="dark">
      Dark
    </a>
  </div>
</div>




        <div className="flex justify-end">
          <Link href='/login' className='relative flex h-10 py-4 px-7 justify-center items-center rounded-2xl bg-blue-600 self-center text-zinc-50 text-center text-sm not-italic font-semibold hover:bg-blue-700'>Авторизоваться</Link>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </header>
    <script src="/ChangeTheme.js" />
    </>
  )
}
```

**Script**
The script code for the button is taken ready-made from the official Preline UI documentation

```
const HSThemeAppearance = {
    init() {
        const defaultTheme = 'default'
        let theme = localStorage.getItem('hs_theme') || defaultTheme

        if (document.querySelector('html').classList.contains('dark')) return
        this.setAppearance(theme)
    },
    _resetStylesOnLoad() {
        const $resetStyles = document.createElement('style')
        $resetStyles.innerText = `*{transition: unset !important;}`
        $resetStyles.setAttribute('data-hs-appearance-onload-styles', '')
        document.head.appendChild($resetStyles)
        return $resetStyles
    },
    setAppearance(theme, saveInStore = true, dispatchEvent = true) {
        const $resetStylesEl = this._resetStylesOnLoad()

        if (saveInStore) {
            localStorage.setItem('hs_theme', theme)
        }

        if (theme === 'auto') {
            theme = window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches ? 'dark' : 'default'
        }

        document.querySelector('html').classList.remove('dark')
        document.querySelector('html').classList.remove('default')
        document.querySelector('html').classList.remove('auto')

        document.querySelector('html').classList.add(this.getOriginalAppearance())

        setTimeout(() => {
            $resetStylesEl.remove()
        })

        if (dispatchEvent) {
            window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('on-hs-appearance-change', {detail: theme}))
        }
    },
    getAppearance() {
        let theme = this.getOriginalAppearance()
        if (theme === 'auto') {
            theme = window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches ? 'dark' : 'default'
        }
        return theme
    },
    getOriginalAppearance() {
        const defaultTheme = 'default'
        return localStorage.getItem('hs_theme') || defaultTheme
    }
}
HSThemeAppearance.init()

window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').addEventListener('change', e => {
    if (HSThemeAppearance.getOriginalAppearance() === 'auto') {
        HSThemeAppearance.setAppearance('auto', false)
    }
})

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    const $clickableThemes = document.querySelectorAll('[data-hs-theme-click-value]')
    const $switchableThemes = document.querySelectorAll('[data-hs-theme-switch]')

    $clickableThemes.forEach($item => {
        $item.addEventListener('click', () => HSThemeAppearance.setAppearance($item.getAttribute('data-hs-theme-click-value'), true, $item))
    })

    $switchableThemes.forEach($item => {
        $item.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
            HSThemeAppearance.setAppearance(e.target.checked ? 'dark' : 'default')
        })

        $item.checked = HSThemeAppearance.getAppearance() === 'dark'
    })

    window.addEventListener('on-hs-appearance-change', e => {
        $switchableThemes.forEach($item => {
            $item.checked = e.detail === 'dark'
        })
    })
})
```

**tailwind.config.js**
I added everything to tailwind.config.js according to the Preline UI documentation

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  darkMode: 'media',
  content: [
    "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
 
    // Or if using `src` directory:
    "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    'node_modules/preline/dist/*.js',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [
    require('tailwind-scrollbar'),
    require('preline/plugin'),
  ],
  
}
```